# Programmatically changing project.properties in Android

Tags: android

Can I programmatically change the content of project.properties in my Android app?
This is needed because I want to include some libraries only in certain conditions and not always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change project dependencies at runtime. The .apk that is created by Android will be exported from you IDE and all of the libraries that application may need to use have to be the part of the .apk.